# How to find child view outside rowdatabound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have tow grid views master grid is `gridpurchase` and child grid is `gvItems`

I am trying to hide some columns in gvItems when exporting the grids to excel file.

i have tried the below code but it didn't work

**Exporting code**

```
protected void btnexcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridpurchase.DataSource = po.GetPurchaseOrders();
    gridpurchase.DataBind();
    GridView gvItems = gridpurchase.FindControl("gvItems") as GridView;
    gvItems.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    gridpurchase.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridpurchase.Rows)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            for (int i = cell.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (cell.Controls[i] is Image)
                {
                    Image img = cell.Controls[i] as Image;


                    if (img.ImageUrl.Contains("plus.png") || img.ImageUrl.Contains("minus.png"))
                    {
                        cell.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    gridpurchase.Caption = "Purchase Orders Report";
    System.Web.HttpContext curContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    System.IO.StringWriter strWriter = null;
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = null;
    curContext.Response.Clear();
    curContext.Response.Buffer = true;
    curContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("PurchaseOrdersReport", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) + ".xls");
    curContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    curContext.Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset=UTF-8>");
    strWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    htmlWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
    gridpurchase.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    curContext.Response.Write(strWriter.ToString());
    curContext.Response.End();
}
```

**Grid-view**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridpurchase" OnRowCommand="gridpurchase_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gridpurchase_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="RequisitionID" GridLines="None" runat="server" CssClass="table text-nowrap" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="imgPlus" runat="server" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="img/plus.png" Style="cursor: pointer" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlproducts" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvItems" CssClass="table table-bordered" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemName" HeaderText="Item Name" SortExpression="ItemName" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierName" HeaderText="Supplier Name" SortExpression="SupplierName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseOrderCode" HeaderText="Purchase Order Code" SortExpression="PurchaseOrderCode" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please post the remaining code about how you're creating the Excel sheet.

Comment: the code is posted now

Comment: what all columns do you wanna remove from your gridview before exporting to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your markup, there is a `gvItems` GridView inside of each row of `gridpurchase`. You can retrieve every child GridView in your main loop:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridpurchase.Rows)
{
    GridView gvItems = row.FindControl("gvItems") as GridView;
    gvItems.Columns[0].Visible = false;

    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `foreach` loop like this

```
gridpurchase.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridpurchase.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

This will remove the first column from your `asp:GridView`